# Any examples of SQLalchemy 0.7, UPDATE using from_statement()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a quick one-off migration script that updates a single field in a table with half a million rows.

Since I hadn't planned on writing out full models for the joins I'm doing to fetch the initial ~25000 rows of data, I've been trying to figure out how to do an UPDATE statement using a from_statement() call and using my own raw sql, but I can't find any examples.

Along with that, SQLalchemy is throwing an error. Here's an example of my call and error:

```
mydb = self.session()
mydb.query().from_statement(
    """
    UPDATE my_table
    SET settings=mysettings
    WHERE user_id=myuserid AND setting_id=123
    """).params(mysettings=new_settings, myuserid=user_id).all()
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sample_script.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sample_script.py", line 108, in main
    migrate.set_migration_data()
  File "./sample_script.py", line 100, in set_migration_data
    """).params(mysettings=new_settings, myuserid=user_id).all()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1267, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1361, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1364, in _execute_and_instances
    result = self.session.execute(querycontext.statement, params=self._params, mapper=self._mapper_zero_or_none())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 251, in _mapper_zero_or_none
    if not getattr(self._entities[0], 'primary_entity', False):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using MySQL.

Per Samy's suggestion, I tried this:

```
mydb.execute(
    "UPDATE mytable SET settings=:mysettings WHERE user_id=:userid AND setting_id=123",
    {'userid': user_id, 'mysettings': new_settings}
    )
```

This had no effect. I don't get any errors, but the statement doesn't seem to actually execute, as the row does not change. If I manually cut and paste the query that gets logged from the echo=True option, the row updates in the database just fine.

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Samy's suggestion was correct but the .execute() call only works on 'engine', not 'session', so this worked just fine:

```
self.engine.execute(
    "UPDATE mytable SET settings=:mysettings WHERE user_id=:userid AND setting_id=123",
    {'userid': user_id, 'mysettings': new_settings}
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is rather strange, according to the docs, the [from_statement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=from_statement#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) is used for `SELECT` statements.

> Execute the given SELECT statement and return results.

I could be looking at the wrong function, or it may be possible to use other type of statements, Im not really sure.

You could just use `execute` since it can do any type of statement, heres a quick example.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

session = sessionmaker(bind = create_engine('sqlite://'), autocommit = True)()

_ = session.execute('CREATE TABLE my_table (user_id int, setting_id int, settings string)')
for id in xrange(200):
    _ = session.execute('INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, setting_id) VALUES (:user_id, :setting_id)',
        {'user_id':id, 'setting_id':id})

_ = session.execute(
"""
    UPDATE my_table
    SET settings = :mysettings
    WHERE user_id = :user_id AND setting_id = 123
""", {'user_id':123, 'mysettings':'test'})

r = session.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_id = :user_id', {'user_id':123}).fetchall()
print r

[(123, 123, u'test')]
```

note that this isn't really the best way to use `sqlalchemy`, which was designed to create a dry environment, decoupled from a specific db backend, though you probably have your reasons for using raw sql versus its ORM.

Comment: Hi Samy, I also tried to use execute() as you suggested (see my update in my original question) but it didn't seem to actually run.

Comment: make sure you flush the session, `mydb.flush()`

Comment: I didn't try a session.flush, but using the engine itself executed the query just fine. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: no problem, glad I could be of help, hope you keep using/enjoying sqlalchemy, its great.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the proper parameter syntax; the format depends entirely on your database adapter. For example, some adapters support `:name` paramaters, in which case you are missing those colons in your query:

```
mydb.query().from_statement(
    """
    UPDATE my_table
    SET settings=:mysettings
    WHERE user_id=:myuserid AND setting_id=123
    """).params(mysettings=new_settings, myuserid=user_id).all()
```

The [DBAPI 2.0 spec](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) supports several formats, including positional parametrs with `?` and `%s` placeholders, and named parameters in the above form and as `%(name)s` formatting. You need to review your database adapter documentation to find out what is supported.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Adding colons didn't help. I had tagged my question with MySQL but should have specified it in the text of my question. I'll try to find the documentation I need, but might just switch to a raw mysql driver to get this done faster.

Comment: `mysqldb` uses `%s` parameters (positional).

Comment: Thanks, tried that too, and the error went away but nothing actually wrote to the database.

Comment: Did you commit the transaction? `